# Is it possible to change the meta tag in css

Tags: html, css

I wonder, is it possible to change @viewport of Meta tag in css for a site.I've written this code in the head of my html code :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.65, maximum-scale=1">
```

and when i want to applicate some modification with css on responsive mode it doesn't work on some devices.
it took me to this size on media query and still there is no response on some devices like ipad pro

```
@media (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 1300px) {}
```

I haven't been able to make it work

Comment: Could you rephrase your question to be more clear on what you are asking?

Comment: I wanna change " initial-scale=0.65 " attribut with css to have control all the devices in responsive mode

Comment: Not only can you not change the content of a meta tag, you would only change the initial zoom level, like it would more zoomed out, which is not what you would likely want. You can simply use media queries to do that.

Comment: You could try using the correct form of the media query `@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 1300px).{/* Style Rules here */}`

Comment: thank you i'm sure now about my reasoning